# vertical grid line not taking full hight of the canvas in chart js 3.3.2

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

As i just migrate from version 2.9.4 to 3.2.2 every thing working fine. the only one issue that i facing is vertical gird line not taking full hight of the canvas here is [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9pdc1e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart-wrapper%2Fchart-wrapper.component.css). [image]

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming that instead of defining `scales.y.grid.display: false`, `scales.y.grid.drawOnChartArea: false` would work, but it doesn't.

As a workaround, you can define `scales.y.grid.color` as shown below.

```
scales: {
  y: {        
    grid: {
      color: ['rgb(180,180,180)', null, null, null, 'rgb(180,180,180)'],
      drawTicks: false
    },
    ...
```

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-bar-border?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and see how it works.